# How to specify Constraints in XSD (XML Schema Definition)?

Tags: xml, xsd, uml, constraints

### Problem

I want to modell the following in *XSD* (XML Schema definition).

I have the following relationship between three classes:

[image]

**Textuell description:**

- Each **Widget** references *0 or more* **Actions**
- Each **Trigger** references *one* **Widget** and *one* **Action**
- **Widgets** may be referenced by *0 or more* **Triggers**
- **Actions** may be referenced by *0 ore more* **Widgets** and *0 or more* **Triggers**
- The **Action** referenced by a **Trigger** must also be referenced by "the **Triggers** **Widget**" (and thats the problem)

In my *XSD* each class is modelled as a `complexType`.

### Question

Is it possible to to model the constraint (orange note, last point) in *XSD*? If yes, how? In UML I'd use a *Composite Structure Diagram* or *OCL*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is referred to as a co-constraint: you want to put a rule into `Trigger`'s definition that impacts the content of two other things at the same time: something in `Widget` must contain something from `Action`.

You can't do that with XSD, but you can do it with [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/).   Schematron will  let you write a rule with an [XPath expression that checks a contains relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931499/xpath-expression-to-find-elements-whose-tag-name-contains-name).   That Xpath expression would then be your rule that you'd check against.

Comment: Yes, I think that does answer your question.  Here's an additional link that might be helpful, but I don't think it changes the answer:  http://www.w3.org/wiki/Co-occurrence_constraints

Comment: Hmmm, in this [article](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/ch09_04.htm) they use some xpath expressions to implement some constraint. Isn't this *XSD* or not applicable to my problem?

Comment: Ah, so that xPath expession navigates through my XSD, and not through my XML as desired, right?

Comment: The context there is that this selector says what the key, keyref, or unique constraint applies to.