# How to get Element by partial tag name from org.w3c.dom.Document Java

Tags: java, soap, domdocument

I'm consuming a third party SOAP API, which gives me "random" XML result. Please look at the following samples to understand what I mean by random.

Sample 1:

```
<test1Interface>
....
</test1Interface>
```

Sample 2:

```
<test2Interface>
....
</test2Interface>
```

Sample 3:

```
<test14Interface>
....
</test14Interface>
```

Now I'm trying to get this element by its `TagName` as follows:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("test14Interface"); // Please assume that document is being initialized properly.
```

Since the `TagName` itself keeps on varying for different SOAP requests that I execute, for some requests above code snippet doesn't work. As I'm consuming third party SOAP API, it's not possible for me to change it.

Can anyone suggest me how can I get element from Document by partial TagName?

Comment: Uxe XPath to query the DOM?

Comment: @JimGarrison, Thanks for quick response. Let me search on XPath.

Comment: Are there other elements with stable names that you can use as reference points? It might be easier to find a parent or sibling with xpath and then navigate from there.

Comment: @teppic, Yes, there are parent nodes but the same problem exists with them also. Ultimately it will become as good as traversing the entire document from root node.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @mm759, No. I still haven't found any solution.

Comment: @JimGarrison, I have checked `XPath` but I'm still not able to find how can I get element only by tagname and not by attributes or id. Can you help me with that?

Comment: How to find an element with a tag name that contains a fixed string using XPath: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14932870

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Document.getChildNodes` and then do arbitrary filtering if needed.

Update 2016-12-23: This mainly  applies to a top level element. Recursive searching can be applied for a nested element. Breadth first search is also an option.

Comment: Do you mean to say I have to traverse the entire document and search for the element?

Comment: No, you only have to check the top-level if you want to get the top-level element. I assumed that an element like `test1Interface` is a top-level element because of it's name.

Comment: Traversing the whole tree should not be more than some lines of recursive code, but I agree that XPath is the first candidate for searching in the whole tree.

Comment: Thanks for your response but `test1Interface` is not the first level node.